# Initialization of members when inheriting from extern C struct

Tags: c++, c, inheritance, struct, init

In [Mixing C and C++ Code in the Same Program](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-dev/mixingcandcpluspluscode-305840.html) the following example (slightly abbreviated here to the relevant parts) is given. Assume `buf.h` contains the following:

```
struct buf {
    char* data;
    unsigned count;
};

// some declarations of existing C functions for handling buf...
```

It is then recommended to use

```
extern "C" {
  #include "buf.h"
}

class mybuf : public buf {
public:
    mybuf() : data(0), count(0) { }

    // add new methods here (e.g. wrappers for existing C functions)...
};
```

in order to use the struct within C++ with added features.

However, this clearly will produce the following error:

```
error: class `mybuf' does not have any field named `data'
error: class `mybuf' does not have any field named `count'
```

The reasons for this are explained in [How can I initialize base class member variables in derived class constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405740/how-can-i-initialize-base-class-member-variables-in-derived-class-constructor), [C++: Initialization of inherited field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984215/c-initialization-of-inherited-field), and [Initialize parent's protected members with initialization list (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290733/initialize-parents-protected-members-with-initialization-list-c).

Thus, I have the following two questions:

1. Is the code provided just plainly wrong or am I missing some relevant aspect? (After all, the article seems to stem from a reputable source)
2. What is the correct way to achieve the desired effect (i.e., turning a C struct into a C++ class and adding some convenience methods like, e.g., a constructor, etc.)?

*Update*: Using aggregation initialization as suggested, i.e.,

```
mybuf() : buf{0, 0} {}
```

works, but requires C++11. I therefore add the following question:

3. Using C++03, is there a better way to achieve the desired outcome than using the following constructor?

   ```
   mybuf() {
     data = 0;
     count = 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: Looks like a copy&paste bug. Earlier on the same page, the author implemented a class `mybuf` having `data` and `count` members.

Comment: why do you put a extern "C" around your struct? there is no need.

Comment: @CyberSpock See the original source of the code, this is about mixing C and C++ code and the header file contains some function declarations, I've edited the code above to make this clear.

Comment: @godfatherofpolka a struct is a struct whether it is C or C++. there is no reason to wrap it in an extern "C" block. Your question is not about mixing C-C++ it is about initializing member variables in the base class.

Comment: @CyberSpock Yes, you're right, the extern "C" is not relevant to the problem, but I kept it there to provide some context of the question, in particular to highlight that the struct is given as a pure C struct and initialization can thus not happen on the struct level (which would be the obvious answer in case it was a C++ struct).

Comment: @godfatherofpolka personally i would do composition instead, then it would be more self-contained where the class instance could take ownership of the contents of buf. But it depends on how you want to use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you can use a c++11 compatible compiler then this would be a perfect use case for an initializer list using [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

```
mybuf() : buf{0, 0}
{}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! What would be the correct way if you can't use C++11?

Answer (score 3):

One "correct" way, if your compiler is C++11 capable, is to use e.g.

```
mybuf() : buf{0, 0} {}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! What would be the correct way if you can't use C++11?

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with mixing C and C++. You're trying to initialise members that don't exist; that they exist in a base class isn't enough. You need to initialise the base itself.

In this case, use aggregate initialisation:

```
class mybuf : public buf
{
public:
    mybuf() : buf{0, 0} {}
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! What would be the correct way if you can't use C++11?

Comment: GCC's extension, perhaps; `buf({0,0})`

Answer (score 2):

```
class mybuf : public buf {
public:
    mybuf();    
    // add new methods here (e.g. wrappers for existing C functions)...
};

const buf init = {0,0};

mybuf::mybuf() : buf(init) {};
```

will work.

I have seen this work with some compilers, but don't have a standard handy to check if it is standard or an extension.

```
class mybuf : public buf {
public:
    mybuf() : buf(init) { }

    // add new methods here (e.g. wrappers for existing C functions)...

    private:

    const buf init = {0,0};
};
```

Comment: As to your second method: GCC 4.9 [accepts it](http://goo.gl/ixNWEG), CLang 3.6rc2 [gives a `-Wuninitialized` warning](http://goo.gl/yUxcF9) on the constructor line,  ICC 13 [rejects it](http://goo.gl/GnHkY6) with an error 409 on the constructor line, and MSVC 17 (VS2012) rejects the initializer with a C2059 'unexpected {' error followed by C2334 'unexpected token(s) preceding '{'' and then a C2065 'undeclared identifier' at the constructor definition.  I'd say it's either a GCCism/GCC extension, or UB.